# Write to file with a structure

Tags: ruby

I want to write to a file in Ruby:

```
File.open(yourfile, 'w')
```

I want to push text into this file but with a format, for example something like:

```
                                    Title
                                 subheading
               some text here
                    subtext here
               ------------------------------------------- 
               sometext here
                    subtext here
               -------------------------------------------
```

not sure how i could write with this format to a file?

Comment: You'd do so in the same way you'd print something like that to the console, honestly.

Comment: I think you might want to look into printf : http://www.evc-cit.info/cit020/beginning-programming/chp_04/file_printf.html
Something like `File.open(yourfile, "w") {|f| f.printf("%55s", line) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the string before saving it to the file, and the formatting will be preserved:

```
 string = <<-TXT
                      #{title}
                   #{subheading}
 #{text1}
      #{subtext1}
 ------------------------------------------- 
 #{text2}
      #{subtext2}
 ------------------------------------------
 TXT

 File.open("my file", 'w') { |f| f.write(string) }
```

Although if you're trying to intelligently center text (like title and subheading) you will need to use a formatter like `printf` which someone else suggested